# Можно ли получить массив точек из svg path

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, svg, математика, path

Подскажите, можно ли получить массив точек из svg path? [image: скриншот]

Серая стрелка это path, который может менять свой угол (может быть прямой или эллипсовидной), мне нужно на нем расположить элемент управления (красный круг), но для этого я должен знать где находится полоска в каждый момент времени. Для этого я и хотел получить массив всех точек, после чего указать одну из них в качестве координат

Answer (score 1):

Думаю будет необходимо вручную делать расчет кубической кривой безье. Тут есть неплохое описание (для четырёх точек): https://learn.javascript.ru/bezier